# Boost Deserialization Exception : Invalid input stream

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-serialization

I am trying to send an object of class Student over the socket(non-boost) using the boost serialization. I am able to serialize data and send it over the socket.
Now the problem is I receive it on the other side (OK ). But when I try to deserialize it, I get boost archive exception: input stream error.
not sure where I am making a mistake.
Here the Code:

```
class Student
{
public:
double Age;
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & Age;
}

};
```

Sender :

```
Student one;
one.Age = 16.50;
std::stringstream ofs;
    // save data to archive
    {
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << one;
    }
write(sockfd, ofs.str().c_str(), sizeof (struct Student));
```

Receiving end:

```
Student stud;
char  buf[512];
read( recv_sock , &buf, sizeof (struct Student));
    std::string temp;
    temp.assign(buf);
    std::cout<<temp<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Read bytes "<<valread<<" bytes<<"<<buf<<"\n";

    std::stringstream ifs;
    ifs<<temp;
    {
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs); // Exception occurs here
    ia >> stud;
    }
```

Any pointers to this issue would be appreciated